# Base64 PDF Files PHP

Tags: php, pdf, base64, encode

Is it ok if we convert PDF to base64 and then store it in database? Although I know that it takes more space but space is not an issue for me. What are the pros and cons of the latter?

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's probably no advantage to storing it as Base64. MySQL and PostgreSQL have great support for binary BLOBs, as do most other databases. In addition to taking up more space, the encoding and decoding overhead will hurt your performance.

Comment: how can i upload pdf as blob? I don't to want store it on the system physically

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+upload+binary+blob http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042599/storing-base64-encoded-data-as-blob-or-text-datatype