# Converting Image Data into Base64 String For MySQL Blob and Decoding it Back

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, base64, urlsession

I'm trying to send data (first name, last name, age, image) to a **MySQL** database.  And I can.  The following is what I have.

```
class PostViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func selectTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        postData()
    }

    func postData() {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://www.mywebsite.tv/post.php")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let fName = firstField.text!
        let lName = lastField.text!
        let ageStr = ageField.text!
        let image = imageView.image!
        guard let pictStr = convertImageBase64(image: image) else {
            return
        }
        let postString = "a=\(fName)&b=\(lName)&c=\(ageStr)&d=\(pictStr)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
        }
        task.resume()
    }

    func convertImageBase64(image: UIImage) -> String? {
        guard let pictData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
            return nil
        }
        let strBase64: String = pictData.base64EncodedString(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions.lineLength64Characters)
        return strBase64
    }
}
```

And populating `UITableView` with data from MySQL..

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, DataModelProtocol {
    // MARK: - Variables
    var myItems = NSArray()

    // MARK: - IBOutlets
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // somehow loading data //    
    }

    // MARK: - TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myItems.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell
        let item: PictureModel = myItems[indexPath.row] as! PictureModel
        cell.firstLabel.text = item.fName
        cell.lastLabel.text = item.lName
        cell.ageLabel.text = item.ageStr
        print(item.pictStr!) // returning iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUh...
        if let img = convertBase64Image(base64String: item.pictStr!) {
            cell.pictureImageView.image = img
        }
        return cell
    }

    func convertBase64Image(base64String: String) -> UIImage? {
        if let pictData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters) {
            return UIImage(data: pictData)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

The thing is `cell.pictureImageView.image` is always nil.  And I now know why.  When I post a picture, a sample base64 string is

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFYAAACACAYAAACRMZ7FAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA\r\nABxp...

And the decoded string that I get is

> iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFYAAACACAYAAACRMZ7FAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA ABxp...

So the `Data.Base64DecodingOptions.ignoreUnknownCharacters` option actually replaces \r\n with a white space.  How can I encode an image and then decode it back the same?

Comment: Why do you do `.lineLength64Characters`? I would simply remove that and you should be good to go.

Comment: @luk2302 's comment should be the answer.

Comment: @luk2302 I don't know anything about Base64, and that's what I got here the other day when I needed to encode image into Base64 for Firebase Database.  How can I change the convertImageBase64 function?  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding binary data and then storing in a `BLOB` column?  Just store the raw binary.

Comment: @eggyal  Thanks.  It's just a suggestion that I got from some web site.  Thanks for advice.  I'll change it.

Comment: @ElTomato: You might like to read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14042709).

Comment: @eggyal That's very nice of you.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @eggyal It's just that it was also a suggestion by many here for Firebase Database.  So I've used it here as well.

Comment: @eggyal How would you change my 'postString' so that it could be sent to MySQL as raw binary as you've suggested?

Comment: @ElTomato: You can still `POST` the data to the HTTP server in Base64-encoded form if you want (it's definitely an easy approach, but look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163136) for details on how you can submit raw binary as `multipart/formdata` if you want—although you might decide to use a third party library to do much of the grunt for you); I'm just saying that, once received at the HTTP server, it should be stored in MySQL in raw form: i.e. *decode* it first and then store in the database.

Comment: @eggyal Thanks,  eggyal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the `.lineLength64Characters` options:

```
func convertImageBase64(image: UIImage) -> String? {
    guard let pictData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        return nil
    }
    let strBase64: String = pictData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
    return strBase64
}
```

That way the string will not have a `\r\n` in it in the first place.

Comment: I see.  Not nil but [].  I'll try it.

Comment: Thanks.  I don't get my image back, though.  Of course, that's not fault.

Comment: @ElTomato wait a second, I "changed" the wrong function, please check again, you should change the `convertImageBase64` method, the other method should have been fine.