# Storing base64 encoded signatures in database

Tags: jquery, mysql

What is the best way to store a base 64 encoded signature on a MySQL database? I can't use varchar as I have counted that some of my signatures exceed the character limit.

I am using jSignature to get the string. Is this a good method of storing the signature? I prefer this instead of storing it as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the base64 string in a **TEXT** column type. Don't use **BLOB**.

Comment: Hi, may I know why shouldn't I use BLOB? Also, should I shift this column into its own table? Would it help performance?

Comment: You can read more here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042599/storing-base64-encoded-data-as-blob-or-text-datatype

Comment: The advice in the linked answer is not relevant here.  The cautionary advice in the other answer is about not storing binary data in the database by base-64 encoding it.  Here, the base-64 encoding of the values is incidental.