# How to convert Base64 String to Image and save image to folder and get the file path in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Ho can I convert my Base64 String to an image(jpg, png, etc) and save that image to a folder and get the image file path? In my code below I am getting the the $Photo 1,2 and 3 have Base64 String inside.

PHP API:

```
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $json_obj = json_decode($json_str);
    $EmpNo = $json_obj->EmpNo;
    $Date = $json_obj->CafDate;
    $CustomerID = $json_obj->CustomerID;
    $StartTime = $json_obj->StartTime;
    $EndTime = $json_obj->EndTime;
    $Photo1 = $json_obj->Photo1;
    $Photo2 = $json_obj->Photo2;
    $Photo3 = $json_obj->Photo3;
    $Remarks = $json_obj->Remarks;
    $OthersText = $json_obj->OthersText;
    $Rekorida = $json_obj->Rekorida;
    $Merchandizing = $json_obj->Merchandizing;
    $TradeCheck = $json_obj->TradeCheck;
    $Others = $json_obj->Others;
    $GPS = $json_obj->GPS;
    $CafDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($Date));
```

Comment: Is this a datatype issue? Save it as a varchar or similar as it's just a string. Might be easier.

Comment: @Dammeul how can I display the image if its a string?

Comment: @Dammeul the data inside $Photo1 is a very very long base64 string is it ok to save it as a varchar?

Comment: Probs a better datatype than varchar to be honest, and I'm positive you can convert base64 back to an image though unsure off the top of my head.  HTML allows you to use base64 directly as the image source <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhE....." />

Comment: Though unsure how your rendering this / how your using it in C#

Comment: It's also not recommended on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042599/storing-base64-encoded-data-as-blob-or-text-datatype to store base64 in your db

Comment: But it alludes to using TEXT over BLOB (or VARCHAR as I through out there)

Comment: @Dammeul can you show me how to convert base 64 string into image and save the image to a folder and get the image path?

Comment: Do you need this in C# or PHP?

Comment: @Dammeul PHP sir based on my code

Comment: You really don't want to save arbitrary binary files in your database, it bloats your records, massively increases your database size, and can make restoring the database unnecessarily slow. Databases are terrible at storing files, and encoding it in Base64 makes an already miserable situation even worse. Store these on disk or with an object-store of some kind like Amazon S3.

Comment: @tadman The data inside $photo1 came from my adroid application I converted the image capture from my app to base64 string so that I can send it to my server

Comment: Why do you need to Base64 anything? Is this going inside JSON for transport? If so, decode it, save it on disk, and save a path to the on-disk location in the database. That's the most efficient method.

Comment: @tadman how? can you show me?

Comment: With the [decoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) function. Handling file attachments is a lot more complicated than you'd think, so I'd strongly encourage you to use a framework that has some support for these. Frameworks come in many forms from really lean like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to exceptionally full-featured like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and many spots in between.

Comment: @tadman can you show me without using frameworks?

Comment: Sorry. I don't have the two years necessary to explain how that's done properly and securely. I'm not being sarcastic here. Arbitrary file upload is how your site gets hacked. Someone will eventually upload an "image" that's actually PHP code and they'll compromise your site if you're not extremely careful. A framework will not only be secure, it will make it easy to use Amazon, Azure, or other stores, and will help you generate thumbnails, etc.